# Macports: libgnome-keyring taking days (or forever) to build

Tags: macos, macports

I have upgraded to mavericks and I am following the instructions to upgrade MacPorts, but it is taking days to rebuild libgnome-keyring - I stopped it after three days and deleted it from my "myports.txt" file and restarted - and it was reloaded as a dependency and is now in its second day of building.

Is this behaviour normal? Is there a fix if it's not?

**update**

This is the output...

```
--->  Computing dependencies for libgnome-keyring
--->  Fetching archive for libgnome-keyring
--->  Attempting to fetch libgnome-keyring-3.10.1_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2 from http://mse.uk.packages.macports.org/sites/packages.macports.org/libgnome-keyring
--->  Attempting to fetch libgnome-keyring-3.10.1_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/libgnome-keyring
--->  Attempting to fetch libgnome-keyring-3.10.1_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2 from http://nue.de.packages.macports.org/macports/packages/libgnome-keyring
--->  Fetching distfiles for libgnome-keyring
--->  Attempting to fetch libgnome-keyring-3.10.1.tar.xz from http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/libgnome-keyring/3.10/
--->  Verifying checksums for libgnome-keyring
--->  Extracting libgnome-keyring
--->  Configuring libgnome-keyring
--->  Building libgnome-keyring
```

Been at this point for about three days now...

**Update** Building via sudo port -d install libgnome-keyring... full output at http://pastebin.com/WhE5zYhu but final part below (sits at this):

```
--->  Building libgnome-keyring
DEBUG: Executing org.macports.build (libgnome-keyring)
DEBUG: Environment: CPATH='/opt/local/include'      CC_PRINT_OPTIONS_FILE='/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_libgnome-keyring/libgnome-keyring/work/.CC_PRINT_OPTIONS' LIBRARY_PATH='/opt/local/lib' CC_PRINT_OPTIONS='YES' MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.9'
DEBUG: Assembled command: 'cd"/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_libgnome-keyring/libgnome-keyring/work/libgnome-keyring-3.10.1" && /usr/bin/make -j4 -w all'
DEBUG: Executing command line:  cd"/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_libgnome-keyring/libgnome-keyring/work/libgnome-keyring-3.10.1" && /usr/bin/make -j4 -w all 
make: Entering directory
`/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_libgnome-keyring/libgnome-keyring/work/libgnome-keyring-3.10.1'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory
`/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_libgnome-keyring/libgnome-keyring/work/libgnome-keyring-3.10.1'
Making all in .
make[2]: Entering directory
`/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_libgnome-keyring/libgnome-keyring/work/libgnome-keyring-3.10.1'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory
`/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_libgnome-keyring/libgnome-keyring/work/libgnome-keyring-3.10.1'
Making all in egg
make[2]: Entering directory
`/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_libgnome-keyring/libgnome-keyring/work/libgnome-keyring-3.10.1/egg'
Making all in .
make[3]: Entering directory
`/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_libgnome-keyring/libgnome-keyring/work/libgnome-keyring-3.10.1/egg'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory 
`/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_libgnome-keyring/libgnome-keyring/work/libgnome-keyring-3.10.1/egg'
Making all in tests
make[3]: Entering directory
`/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_libgnome-keyring/libgnome-keyring/work/libgnome-keyring-3.10.1/egg/tests'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory
`/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_libgnome-keyring/libgnome-keyring/work/libgnome-keyring-3.10.1/egg/tests'
make[2]: Leaving directory
`/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_libgnome-keyring/libgnome-keyring/work/libgnome-keyring-3.10.1/egg'
Making all in library
make[2]: Entering directory
 `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_libgnome-keyring/libgnome-keyring/work/libgnome-keyring-3.10.1/library'
Making all in .
make[3]: Entering directory
`/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_libgnome-keyring/libgnome-keyring/work/libgnome-keyring-3.10.1/library'

/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link /usr/bin/clang  -Wall    -Wchar-subscripts -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes   -Wnested-externs -Wpointer-arith    -Wcast-align -Wsign-compare     -pipe -Os -arch x86_64 -g -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-sign-compare  -L/opt/local/lib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -arch x86_64 -o libgnome-keyring-testable.la   gkr-callback.lo gkr-debug.lo gkr-misc.lo gkr-operation.lo gkr-session.lo gnome-keyring.lo gnome-keyring-memory.lo gnome-keyring-utils.lo ../egg/libegg.la -L/opt/local/lib -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl  -L/opt/local/lib -ldbus-1  -L/opt/local/lib -lgcrypt -lgpg-error -L/opt/local/lib -lgcrypt -lgpg-error 
libtool: link: rm -fr  .libs/libgnome-keyring-testable.lax
```

Comment: Could you run the command again but with the `-d` (debug) flag to show more output?

Comment: I am using the restore_ports.tcl script (as per the upgrade instructions) and I don't know any TCL - can you tell me where to insert the flag in the script?

Comment: Use `sudo port -d install libgnome-keyring` to run just that portion with debugging on.

Comment: Full output at http://pastebin.com/WhE5zYhu

Comment: The log looks OK = try a `port clean libgnome-keyring` and try again

Comment: just gets to the build bit, and then remains in the build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
sudo port uninstall libgnome-keyring
sudo port clean --all libgnome-keyring
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port -uc upgrade outdated
sudo port -d install libgnome-keyring
```

I just tried it myself and have considerably more output in [my debug log](http://pastebin.com/PBkZWScw). I'm wondering if your port tree is out of date maybe?

EDIT: I see your log has this line:

```
DEBUG: Skipping completed org.macports.configure (libgnome-keyring)
```

Which suggests the port hasn't been cleaned properly. Is that still showing up after doing the above?

Also I see this:

```
compiler clang 421.11.66 not blacklisted because it doesn't match {clang < 211.10.1}
```

What version of XCode are you running? Not 4.2 I hope? `xcodebuild -version` will tell you. You should be on 5.0.2. If you have to install or update from the App Store, you'll also want to run `xcode-select --install` to install the CLI tools.

Comment: Did you look at the full output in the pastebin?

Comment: Yup, mine (linked above) is 3 times as long. Though I don't see any errors in yours, clearly something is wrong.

Comment: This is just the same - gets to build and then hits the processors hard but no sign that it will complete the build.

Comment: Any info from the XCode version check?

Comment: Won't be near the box until Monday morning I'm afraid.

Comment: It's xcode 4.5.2 - I will update that now

Comment: Upgrading xcode did indeed fix the issue